# Applescript Delete Excel Columns that Have Certain Text in Row 1

Tags: excel, applescript

I need an applescript that deletes any column in excel that doesn't contain the text I want in row 1. My script is below for deleting the columns that contain "REC_ID, F_STATUS, or EVENT_ID" in row 1.

```
set myValues to "REC_ID, F_STATUS, EVENT_ID"
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
set columnCount to (((count of columns of used range of active sheet)) + 1)
repeat with i from columnCount to 1 by -1
    set cellValue to value of cell ("1" & i)
    if cellValue is not in myValues then
        delete column i
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

I keep getting this error error "Microsoft Excel got an error: The object you are trying to access does not exist" number -1728 from value of cell "133".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your line:

```
set cellValue to value of cell ("1" & i)
```

to this:

```
set cellValue to value of row 1 of column i
```

..which appears to fix it.

Comment: Works like a champ. Thanks!